# SD card reader won't show in file explorer

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-explorer, sd-card

I have a Transcend USB 3.0 SD and MicroSD card reader. When I plug it in, it won't show up in the windows 7 file explorer, but it shows up properly in DiskPart and device manager in windows 7 which says it is operating properly. I Cannot access any files on any SD card placed in the adapter. I have another old SD adapter that works fine, but I want to replace it with the non-functioning adapter. It used to work fine when i first got it, So the problem is most likely Windows file explorer.

Comment: Does it work on other Windows PC's?

Comment: Yes it works on another windows 7 pc

Comment: All I can suggest it to uninstall and reinstall all the USB root hub drivers in Device Manager. Do this with all usb devices disconnected besides keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Open disk management by pressing windows + R and typing `diskmgmt.msc`. Check if the card reader has a drive letter assigned to it. If not add one by right clicking and going to "change drive letters and paths"

Comment: @mt025 "it shows up properly in DiskPart and device manager "

Comment: You can either post an answer stating what your fix is, or ask the person who gave you a solution to post it as an answer. Either way will give you the option of "accepting" an answer (green tick) which will mark your question as solved. This is not a forum and we don't need to mangle titles to mark things as fixed or working.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's and it's answers are a train wreck (low quality) + it's old and OP will probably never return to clarify or accept an answer. I really fail to see how old threads like these benefit SU.

Answer (score 0):

Open a dos command window and type *set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1*

Click Start, then right-click Computer on the right menu and select Manage or else press ***Windows key + r*** and enter ***compmgmt.msc***

When it launches click and expand Device Manager on the left panel
On the top menu click *View* and select *Show hidden devices*

I don't have a windows computer to hand right now but I believe you should be able to find the offending item or a ghost of your USB drive and uninstall it. It does no harm to completely remove all USB devices as the system will reinstall them on restart. However it may be best to leave that as a last resort.

Answer (score -1):

Typedevmgmt.msc into the search box and press enter. 
 select dev man from the menu .
 If you see any yellow triangle with black exclamation then choose Properties and read the error message in the Device status box. You can read about that error on the internet

.

Comment: letschat, as opposed to the user name you have chosen the StackExchange world is not a chat. Please rework your entry: Avoid abbreviations like "dev man". This is gamer speak and does not serve others searching for solutions. Put a SPACE between the first and second word of your posting. Write the full term of "dev man". Replace "menu ." by "menu." and put the punctuation mark directly behind "internet". Thank you for joining StackExchange.